Azure DevOps custom YAML template parameters to move linked services from DEV to QA
I'm facing a problem while setting up Azure DevOps for a client.
They had no idea how to use Azure Data Factory so all the linked services names are different in DEV/QA/PRD environment, each of them pointing to a different url.
Like this:
-DEV_LINKED_SERVICE_NAME with URL_DEV
-UAT_LINKED_SERVICE_NAME with URL_UAT
-PRD_LINKED_SERVICE_NAME with URL_PRD

Now when I'm trying to move objects from DEV to QA I do use a custom template for parameters so that I can override URL values of the linked services to point in the right environment, the problem is I am not able to change linked services names so now the same pipeline in DEV and QA is pointing to different URLs but with the same linked_service_name, is there any solution to this using YAML templates?
I wouldn't like to show pipeline with DEV naming convention but pointing to QA environment.

Could you please edit your question and include the relevant part of the pipeline code?
